# How to create a text file whose name is a scaned string?

Tags: c, string, file, scanf

I am trying to count the occurrence of character for a string.

The user has two options:

- first, display the result of screen
- second, to store the result in a file but the file name will be a string enter also by user

My real problem is that when in comes to scan the name of the file, it does not work.

The part of my code where `count[]` has integer number represents the occurrence of each character. When I tryed to debug the code it seems like scan step of `out[]` string array was skipped, and it got uncommon characters like `ÿÿtþa`.

```
    printf("Enter 1 if you want to output data on screen\nEnter 2 to output data to file : ");
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    if(input == 1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"%s:\n\"%s\"\n", "characters count in this string", s);
        fprintf( stdout, "%-20s%-4s\n", "character", "count");
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
        fprintf(  stdout, "%-20c%-4d\n", j+65, count[j]);
    }//end of if
    else if(input == 2)
    {
        FILE *Ptr;
        printf("enter file name : ");
        char out[30]= {'\0'};
        scanf("%29[^\n]", out);
        if( (Ptr = fopen(out,"w")) == NULL)
        printf("CAN NOT OPEN FILE\n");
        else
        {
            fprintf(Ptr,"%s:\n\"%s\"\n", "characters count in this string", s);
            fprintf( Ptr, "%-20s%-4s\n", "character", "count");
            for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            fprintf(  Ptr, "%-20c%-4d\n", j+65, count[j]);
        }//end of else
        fclose(Ptr);
      }//end of else
}//end of main
```

Comment: " it seems like scan step of out[] string array was skipped" --> Robust code would checked the return value of `scanf()` and have noticed it was not 1.